# Can't login to github

Tags: git, authentication, github

Hi guys I logout from my github account and trying to login again here this image in the last one I logout github was sent me the 6 digits, here I tried hard and can't login to my account I need help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbpl6.png)

Comment: [Questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic for Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You enabled 2 factor authentication, so there is a code should be sent to you email or phone number whenever you login to verify the login, check your email.

Comment: In the last time I sign out the code was sent to my email this time not sent what should I do?